# CheckChanged not firing when added programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below code which works fine except for the fact that the radio button event for checkchanged is not firing. I can get this working by using postbacks, but I want to avoid that and have it launch my JavaScript. Any insight would be great!

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Register JavaScript
        string javaName = "alert";
        Type javaType = this.GetType();

        ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;
        if (!csm.IsStartupScriptRegistered(javaType, javaName))
        {
            StringBuilder buildScript = new StringBuilder();
            buildScript.Append("<script type=text/javascript>");
           // buildScript.Append("window.alert();");
            buildScript.Append("function myFunction(){");
            buildScript.Append("window.open('jstest.htm','','width=800,height=600')}");
            buildScript.Append("</script>");
            csm.RegisterStartupScript(javaType, javaName, buildScript.ToString());
        }






            //Loop through results
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                //Create yes and no Radio Buttons for each question
                RadioButton radioyes = new RadioButton();
                radioyes.ID = "radioy_" + i.ToString();
                radioyes.GroupName = "Yquestion_" + i;
                radioyes.Text = "yes";
                //radioyes.CheckedChanged += radio_CheckedChanged;
                //radioyes.AutoPostBack = true;
                radioyes.Attributes.Add("checkedchanged", "myFunction()");

                RadioButton radiono = new RadioButton();
                radiono.ID = "radion_" + i.ToString();
                radiono.GroupName = "Yquestion_" + i;
                radiono.Text = "no";
                //radiono.CheckedChanged += radio_CheckedChanged;
                //radiono.AutoPostBack = true;



                //Add dynamic controls to placeholder
                QuestionZone.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("This is a test " + i.ToString()));
                QuestionZone.Controls.Add(radioyes);
                QuestionZone.Controls.Add(radiono);
                QuestionZone.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br><br>"));
            }

        }
```

Comment: You have the checkchanged event register commented out?

Comment: yes, but if you look at the code for the "Yes" button you can see I added the event as an attribute. checkchanged doesn't work but onclick does. My guess is that the checkchanged requires a postback to compare  the state.

Answer (score 1):

Well one other fix may be:

```
  radioyes.Attributes.Add("checkedchanged", "myFunction()");
```

swap above with following:

```
 radioyes.Attributes.Add("onchange", "myFunction()");
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the attribute to "onclick" instead of "checkchanged" since I only an event to fire if the user selects "yes", this seemed to be an acceptable workaround.